# Print JSON nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, laravel-blade

Json object with nested objects, nested objects to be print in for loop of laravel-blade
This is my JSON Object below:

```
var cart = [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pads2",
    "current_price": "450",
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747597.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pads",
    "current_price": "450",
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747555.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pad",
    "current_price": null,
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747521.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747521.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747522.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747522.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 2
  }
]
```

I want to print the `cart.photo[0]` index in for loop

Comment: Do you want to print it in `blade` file?

Comment: yes in blade file like this: <img :src="'/images/product/thumbnail/' + cart.photo['0'] " alt="product-image" class="">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` in the loop in order to access a photo by index:

```js
var cart = [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pads2",
    "current_price": "450",
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747597.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747597.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pads",
    "current_price": "450",
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747555.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747555.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "product_name": "Kinoki Cleansing Detox Foot Pad - 10 Pad",
    "current_price": null,
    "photo": "{\"0\":\"1-big_1595747521.jpg\",\"1\":\"2-big_1595747521.jpg\",\"2\":\"3-big_1595747522.jpg\",\"3\":\"4-big_1595747522.jpg\"}",
    "qty": 2
  }
]

for (const product of cart) {
  const photo = JSON.parse(product.photo);
  console.log(photo[0])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
cart.forEach((item) => console.log(JSON.parse(item.photo)[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var photos = cart.map(c => {
   const photo = JSON.parse(c['photo']);
   return photo[0];
});

console.log(photos);
```